# How to attach WebStorm debugger to an already running node process on a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, debugging, docker-compose, webstorm

There are three service. I want to debug api service through webstorm.

**docker-compose** file

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - '5000:80'
      - "9229:9229"

  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./api:/app

  web:
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./web:/app
```

Using nodemon to run the node server.

```
nodemon -L --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 index.js
```

As it showed, debugger is attached to 9229 port:

[image]

WebStorm configuration to attach the debugger:

[image]

Still the breakpoint did not get hit. Can anyone please help?